# Onclick вставить в ссылку

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть фильтр, который после всех манипуляций выдаёт "значение1"и"значение2", как мне сделать так что бы при клике на 'значение1' происходило заполнение поля input.
Вот что попадает в фильтр

```
{name:"<a href=#>Значение1</a>",val1:365,val2:'',val3:false,val4:true,val5:true,val6:true,},
```

Саму функцию заполнения я написал

```
   function getmesseg(){
    var mynewvar = [  {vaal1:value='25',vaal2:'6',vaal3:'1',}  ];//массив для значениея
    var date3 = mynewvar[0]['vaal1'];
    $('#ddlIntFre').val(date3);
    var temp = $('#ddlIntFre').val();
    };
```

Но вот как сделать что бы происходило наполнение при клике по ссылке?

Comment: по какой ссылке ? `element.on('click',getmesseg);` ?

Comment: Думал так сделать, не фурычит  

 {name:"<a href=# onclick=somefunction();>Срочный удобный</a>",val1:365,val2:'',val3:false,val4:true,val5:true,val6:true,},

Comment: так где вы ссылку то выводите ? сделайте jsfiddle это правда поможет.

Comment: там код большой, ловите фтп

Comment: @нгш сделайте пример в jsfiddle.net это в *разы* ускорит получения ответа :-)

Comment: ок, через 10 мин сделаю))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xk8Zz/2/ на всякий ссылку оставлю http://tarasik78.tmweb.ru/FixedDepositCalculator.htm

Comment: @нгш вы же давно тут вопросы задаете... сделать fiddle значит

 1. выделить проблему
 2. сделать такой fiddle чтобы не работало только то, о чем вы спрашиваете, а вы даже jQuery не подключили....

Answer (score 1):

Имеем `p` и `input`

Html:

```
<p id="p1">
Текст который нам надо скопировать в Input
</p>

<input id ="input1" type="text" value="" />
```

Js:

```
$("#p1").bind("click", function() {
  var p1 = $("#p1").text(); //получаем текст
  $("#input1").val(p1); //заполняем поле текстом
});
```